# How to view the periodogram or FFT of a WAV file in Audacity?

Tags: audacity, wav

I’m trying to visualize the periodogram (or the Fourier transform (FFT)) of a WAV file (not a spectrogram produced by a sliding window). Is it possible to do this using Audacity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have not used this myself, but [found this information on the official Audacity site on “Plot Spectrum”](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/plot_spectrum.html) (under “Analyze > Plot Spectrum”) and it seems to cover what you are talking about.

> Plot Spectrum takes the selected audio (which is a set of sound pressure values at points in time) and converts it to a graph of frequencies (the horizontal scale in Hz) against amplitudes (the vertical scale in dB).

[image: An image of “Plot Spectrum” in Audacity in action.]